# Is there a "quick way" to print a whole int array?

Tags: c, arrays

I wonder, just like there is

`printf("%s",array);`

to print a whole char array, is there a way to print a whole int array with one command instead of a for cycle printing it one by one?

Comment: Using which language? C++, I don't think so, unless you call a function and hide the looping in the function.

Comment: @CrossRoads I would assume C since OP tagged his question as such and used `printf` in their example code

Comment: Note: `printf("%s",array);` does not print a whole char array.  Output stops once a _null character_ is encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box in standard C.

When you pass an array of any type as an argument to a function like `printf` then it decays to a pointer to its first element, losing information about its length.

Strings stored as `char` arrays are special in C, since they are null-terminated. Library functions can take pointers to `char` arrays as parameters and increment the pointer to the null-terminator to determine its length.

If you want to create an extension of `printf` that has a new format specifier for arrays of type `int`, you will need to pass length information to it as well. It's simpler to just have a helper function that also takes the length print out the entire array using a `for` loop, and use that to hide the looping in the calling code.